# Can I ask about my CloudFormation infrastructure template?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a template for some infrastructure using AWS CloudFormation that I'd like reviewed. However, I'm not sure if it's on-topic here; it's YAML that's describing infrastructure, not a program *per se*. Would this be ok to post here?

Comment: Related: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6060/do-configuration-files-constitute-reviewable-code

Comment: I would find this easier to discuss with an example.  Note that the question @rolfl linked distinguishes between Samba config and a .htaccess file.  So the question then becomes whether this template is more like configuration or a .htaccess file.  But how do we evaluate that without an example?  [Is YAML code?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16238005)  I am far more confident of my ability to say whether something is code if I see it rather than just have its potential described.  I am confident that mod_rewrite rules are code.  Port mappings?  Not so much.

Comment: I can put up an example later, but from the comments, it's probably not on- topic. What I'm really looking for is whether my infrastructure is properly set up, which would be more of a Server Fault thing; I'm not so much worried about whether the bits of logic in the template work.